# Varnishncsa truncated referer

Tags: linux, varnish

I have a question concerning varnish and varnishncsa.

In fact I've set up varnishncsa to log requests with this log format :

```
LOG_FORMAT="%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\""
```

But for long **refers**, I noticed that they are truncated, and when checked they are all limited to **247** characters.

I've googled for a long time to figure out what can be the problem, but I didn't find a right answer.
Do someone have ever have the issue, and can someone tell me how varnishncsa works in depth, and this issue can be solved please?

Not all the log entry is truncated, but only the referer field.

Thank in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I solve the issue by a set the **vsl_reclen** value.